# How to display the popup symbol document like in auto-complete?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, slime

While programming in emacs, like Lisp, the auto-complete mode will be popup candidates, also with a document tip after several seconds.

My question is how to display the document tip directly, it is convenient to check the document but in the other buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the following function to a shortcut. Keep in mind that it will need both auto-complete and popup (bundled with auto-complete in older versions and separate in newer ones) to work.

```
(defun popup-documentation-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((position (point))
         (string-under-cursor (buffer-substring-no-properties
                         (progn (skip-syntax-backward "w_") (point))
                         (progn (skip-syntax-forward "w_") (point)))))
    (goto-char position)
    (popup-tip (ac-symbol-documentation (intern string-under-cursor)))))
```